# How to get the nid of current node

Tags: nodes

I need a function to return the `nid` of the current `node` that the current `user` is watching.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are insisting on a **function** then you are looking for `arg` function.

`arg(0)` will return `'node'` and `arg(1)` will return `node nid`.

Provided you must be inside a node.

[**Updated Answer**]

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  if ($nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    /** do something **/  
  }
}
```

**Alternately**

you can get `nid` from node object `$node->nid`

Comment: Oh,arg is very exiting function,but how to use it?can you give me some example?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: If you want the node object directly you can use the function `menu_get_object()`, it will save you a few lines of code

Answer (score 2):

You can access `$node` object. `$node->nid` will return you NID of the node.

There is a hook to help you further to achieve something when user is viewing node -  [hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

There are three parameter of the hook - `$node` (will return node object), `$view_mode` (view mode of the node like full or teaser) &  `$langcode` (language code for rendering).

You can use this hook in your module & write your logic like -

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){//replace your module name with MYMODULE here
  if($node->type == 'article' && $view_mode == 'full'){ //if content type is article & user is on full node view
    //do domething
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change || with &&.Am I right?

Comment: @mahdialikhasi Yeah my mistake, sorry. I have edited the code..